# $(...).intercode is not a function Phone.js

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, typeerror, compatibility

I'm having an issue with a JS plugin I'm using called Phone.js on my Wordpress site. I've included the script after I've loaded my jQuery. Here is my code I used to trigger the addition of the phone field:

```
<code><script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.phone').intercode({
    country: 'CA',
    selectClass: 'countryCodeselect left',
    intercodeFile: './js/countrycodes.json'
    });
    });
    </script></code>
```

This is the error I receive when loading the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).intercode is not a function
```

This issue occurs with phone.js and intlTelInput.min.js, so it isn't specific to one plugin
Any advice would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just to answer the question I figured out what was wrong with my integration.
 The files were being loaded but in an incorrect order, which was preventing my script from using the loaded plugin functions.
I managed to fix the issue and now the phone field is displaying correctly.
Thanks